# Flutter await channel.watch({presence: true})

Tags: getstream-io

I can not add the presence property to the channel in order to watch for users going online or offline. Is there any way around this ? do I have to use something like queryUsers each time I want to listen for their online presence ?

I tried searching the docs, every youtube tutorial, documentation but I have not found anything useful on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the DevRel team at Stream.

We recently merged a PR which exposes the presence property from the channel. (Find the commit [here](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-flutter/commit/cc1ad224e2137177ff41b32d10287c4d79540e33))

This should be released soon alongside the newest version of the SDK. Keep an eye out for any releases and you should be able to use this soon. Hope this helps :)